# How to debug PHP in eclipse in an external browser rather than internal?

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-debugger

How can I make eclipse launch and debug a site on the default browser instead of the interal browser?

I'm using MacOSX, Eclipse PDT 3.0.2 with the Zend Debugger.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Eclipse > Preferences > General > Web Browser.

Select the option for 'Use external web browser', and leave the 'Default system web browser' box ticked.

Comment: Just a note, in Windows the top level menu item is "Window" rather than "Eclipse".

Comment: Why does it have to open a new tab when running a debug configuration, and open yet another new tab when stopping said debug configuration ?